# Use of RUN command in excel

Tags: excel, vba

The code was designed by someone. While testing I'm getting error in the code

```
IntnumbOfchild = Run("ELCOMPN", STRdIM, strTest1st)
```

Can you tell me if its related to tm1? When do we use `RUN` command? I cannot find the macro of this name in the project

Answer (score 1):

Run is not a procedure of the standard libraries in VBA.

- Thus, select the word "Run" it with the mouse cursor, and press <kbd>F2</kbd>:
  [image]
- Take a look where the VBEditor brings you.
- Try to debug there.